# fread loop doesn't read all bytes, and why are the bytes reversed?

Tags: c

I have a file with some test data in it, `"abcde"`. I want to read the data from it into a `uint16_t` buffer a byte at a time, (I'm not interested in the meaning of the data as such, just its binary representation for a checksum) but the final `"e"` isn't being read:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "rb");
uint16_t buffer[1];
while ( fread( buffer, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, fp ) != 0 ) {
  printf("0x%x\n", *(buffer) );
}
```

That outputs:

```
0x6261
0x6463
```

If a `uint8_t` type is used then the output is:

```
0x61
0x62
0x63
0x64
0x65
```

I tried reversing the `size` and `nmemb` arguments to `fread` (e.g. `while ( fread( buffer, 1, 2, fp ) != 0 )` but got:

```
0x6261
0x6463
0x6465
```

Which is probably the least help of all!

This leaves me with 2 main questions:

1. How should I call `fread` to read *all* the characters when using `uint16_t` (but without the repeated datum of the last example)?
2. Why are the bytes reversed when using `uint16_t`? Shouldn't it be `0x6162` and `0x6364`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fread() always reads complete records. And as the size of uint16_t is 2 bytes in a machine whose byte size (CHAR_BIT) is 8 bits, each call to fread() reads multiples of 2 bytes in your code.

You can read the individual bytes for example with fgetc() like this:

```
FILE *f;
uint16_t array[5];
void foo() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        array[i] = fgetc(f);
    }
}
```

The bytes are "reversed" because you're likely running in a little-endian machine.

Comment: Thanks. I won't just be reading text files though, so will `fgetc` be a good choice for those too?

Comment: fgetc might be a little inefficient, but basically, yes, it gets a character (8 bits) in virtually every platform. You might need to pay attention to whether it returns a *signed* or *unsigned* char in some cases, though.

Comment: Note that `fgetc()` typical returns 1 of 257 different values.  Saving directly into `char` loses some information.  Better to save in an `int` first and test for `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

The bytes aren't reversed. You're misreading the output. On your platform, a `uint16` value of `0x1234` means an `0x34` followed by an `0x12`. There's no one right way to store multi-byte values in memory and your platform happens to choose this way.

Don't reverse the parameters to `fread`. If you read a partial value, you don't want to print it. If you want to do something specific in the case where the file is not an even multiple of your data size, decide what and write code to do it.